# Custom Post Search

Tags: custom-post-types, search, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to modify search results for my custom post type. I have clarified that the code I am using is returning users and post ID's but no results are displayed.

Essentially when a search is attempted via the edit-post screen for my custom post, I want the search to check all users by login name, email, nicename, and display name. A further check is then performed for each user found to see if their user ID exists in one of two custom meta keys for my custom post types. If it does, that post should be included in the results.

I am using the `pre_get_posts` hook with the following function...

```
function custom_post_query( $query )    {
        global $pagenow;

        if( !is_post_type_archive( 'my-custom-posttype' ) || !$query->is_main_query() || !$query->is_admin || 'edit.php' != $pagenow )
            return $query;

        if( $query->is_search() )   {
            $users = new WP_User_Query(
                array(
                    'search'            => $_GET['s'],
                    'search_columns'    => array(
                        'user_login',
                        'user_email',
                        'user_nicename',
                        'display_name'
                    )
                )
            ); // WP_User_Query

            if( !empty( $users->results ) ) {
                foreach( $users->results as $user ) {
                    $results = get_posts(
                        array(
                            'post_type'     => 'my-custom-posttype',
                            'post_status'   => 'any',
                            'meta_query'    => array(
                                'relation'  => 'OR',
                                array(
                                    'key'       => '_custom_meta_key1',
                                    'value'     => $user->ID,
                                    'compare'   => '==',
                                    'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key'       => '_custom_meta_key2',
                                    'value'     => $user->ID,
                                    'compare'   => '==',
                                    'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ); // get_posts

                    if( !empty( $results ) )    {
                        foreach( $results as $result )  {
                            $events[] = $result->ID;                                
                        }
                    }

                } // foreach( $users as $user )
            } // if( !empty( $users ) )

            if( !empty( $events ) ) {
                $query->set( 'post__in', $events );
            }
        } // if( $query->is_search() 

        return $query;
    } // custom_post_query
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_query' );
```

**EDITED - Adding resulting WP_Query**
`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS web_wp_posts.ID FROM web_wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND web_wp_posts.ID IN (5818,5881,5717,5655,5636,5592) AND (((web_wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%*mike*%') OR (web_wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%*mike*%'))) AND web_wp_posts.post_type = 'mdjm-event' AND ((web_wp_posts.post_status = 'mdjm-unattended' OR web_wp_posts.post_status = 'mdjm-enquiry' OR web_wp_posts.post_status = 'mdjm-approved' OR web_wp_posts.post_status = 'mdjm-contract' OR web_wp_posts.post_status = 'mdjm-completed' OR web_wp_posts.post_status = 'mdjm-rejected' OR web_wp_posts.post_status = 'mdjm-failed')) ORDER BY web_wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%*mike*%' DESC, web_wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20`

Thanks

Comment: And what is the problem? Where does the code fail? What happens that shouldn't? Also, you don't need to return the query. The query object is passed by reference.

Comment: Per my post... no results are displayed. The page loads fine, but states no posts. I was initially thinking that the `post__in` was the problem. 

As I stated, I have confirmed I have users and post ID's. It's just that no search results are displayed

Comment: Are you sure there are posts matching all of the query requirements? In other words, you are setting `post__in`, but what does the rest of the query look like?

Comment: OK, It starts as ...

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS web_wp_posts.ID FROM web_wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND web_wp_posts.ID IN (5818,5881,5717,5655,5636,5592)` 

which seems ok and confirms that my user lookup and `get_posts` are working, but after that there are a large number of WHERE clauses. I guess what I need to do is get rid of those by essentially removing the default WP_Query and replacing with my own. But I'm not sure of the best way to do this?

Comment: [Edit] that entire generated query into the question please, so I can see exactly what is happening.